# What is the propose of using window.location?.search?.split

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to understand the propose of using `window.location?.search?.split('=')[1]`
and why `id` takes value of `window.location?.search?.split('=')[1]`

**Code:**

```
function EndScreen() {
  const [score, setScore] = React.useContext(ScoreContext);

  /* console.log('history', window.location?.search?.split('=')[1]); */
  return (
    <div className="EndScreen">
      <h1>Test finished</h1>
      <br></br>
      <h3> You scored:</h3>
      <h1 style={{ fontSize: '70px' }}>
        {score} / {Questions?.length}
      </h1>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          FormService.update({
            id: window.location?.search?.split('=')[1],
            data: { score: score }
          })
          .then(() => {
            alert('Score updated');
          })
          .catch(() => {
            alert('Score did NOT update')
          })
        }
      >
        Apply for job
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's fetching the value of the first query parameter. For example if the request was aimed at `host.com/page?param=value` it will return `value`

Answer (score 0):

Its for working with `querystring`:

if your url is , `google.com/user/userData?id=123,email=exp@gmail.com`

we call user and userData `path` & id and email are called `querystrings`

```js
location.search; // Returns:'?id=123,email=exp@gmail.com'

let newArray = location.search.split('=') // Returns:['?id','123',',email','exp@gmail.com']
```

Comment: then `[1]` means it will return just the first querry `id` which is 123 ?